# Show Continuous Progress Bar on DataGridView Fill

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two forms (Main.vb and Schedule.vb).  Main has a toolstripmenu and a panel.  When "View Schedule" is selected from the toolstripmenu, the Schedule form is opened within the Main form's panel.  So it opens as a "sub form".  This works perfectly.

```
Private Sub tsmiScheduleView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsmiScheduleView.Click

Schedule.TopLevel = False
Schedule.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
Schedule.Size = New Size(pnlMain.Width, pnlMain.Height) 'anchors will be disrupted if form does not open to fit with main
Me.pnlMain.Controls.Add(Schedule)
Schedule.Show()

End Sub
```

The problem happens in Schedule.vb, there is a DataGridView there that gets populated via a TableAdapter.  But it takes a long time to load.  So I want to show a Continuous Progress Bar while the DataGridView is loading.

```
Private Sub Schedule_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

' Load main data into the Schedule DataGridView
Me.SchedulViewTable_TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSetSchedule.SchedulViewTable)

End Sub
```

I can get the progress bar to show easy enough, but it freezes when the DataGridView is loading.

I've tried using threads, backgroundworkers, putting the ProgressBar in a seperate form and displaying it from there, and I even nixed my ProgressBar idea for an animated gif using picture boxes. None of these are working for me.  Can anyone help?

As a note, I would love to use this all over my program.  Whenever I run into something that's going to take time I'd like to have an easy way to say: "Okay, display the Continuous Progress Bar on Main.vb until I'm done".

Thanks.

Comment: Is your DataTable already bound to the DataGridView when you execute the Fill command ? What is the size, i.e. number of rows and columns of the DataGridView ?

Comment: Yes the DataTable is already bound. Theres 44,926 rows and 40 columns. Though I am working in our test database, the production database has over 100,000 rows.

Comment: Seems like you need to redesign your app to just pull over/display relevant records. 100Kx40 on the client side seems like a bad idea. Since the code loading the grid is not under your control I doubt you will be able to display its progress. You could fake progress with a timer doing the bar updates.

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataGridView DataSource to null before executing the Fill command.
Then set the DataSource back to DataTable.

If you do that, how long does it take between the binding and the display (I would bet on 5 to 15 seconds)?

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm not looking to shorten the load time.  I can definitely get that done 101 ways.  But I am looking to get a progress bar to animate during the loading of a DataGridView.  I'm assuming this is impossible =(

Comment: I don't see any DataGridView event triggered when the rows count changes during the binding process. The most appropriate would be the RowsAdded event, but it seems that it doesn't work properly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like the only thing to do is load less rows into the DataGridView so there is no need for a progress bar.  Not what I wanted to do but there isn't a way to do what I originally wanted.

I was able to show text, "Loading..." but no animation.